# Windows Forms - ErrorProvider overlapping icons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

I'm using a custom icon in my ErrorProvider with

```
ErrorProvider.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink
```

I've got a problem with overlapping icons using code that is similar to this one:

```
public partial class TestForm : Form
{
    private ErrorProvider _errorProvider1;
    private ErrorProvider _errorProvider2;
    private CheckBox _control1;
    private CheckBox _control2;

    //...


    private void ValidateAll()
    {
        _errorProvider1.Clear();
        _errorProvider2.Clear();

        _errorProvider1.SetError(_control1, string.Empty);
        _errorProvider2.SetError(_control2, string.Empty);

        if(Validate(_control1.Checked))
        {
            _errorProvider1.SetError(_control1, "Error1");
        }

        if(Validate(_control2.Checked))
        {
            _errorProvider2.SetError(_control2, "Error2");
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

I'm interacting with *_control1* while *_control2* has some error (is *Checked*), thus *_errorProvider2* has some error set. Everytime method *ValidateAll* is called it will correctly set *_errorProvider1* for *_control1* but *_control2* *_errorProvider2* will keep drawing extra icons without erasing old ones.

[Starting view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ6iC.png)

[After 'clicking' _control1 multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtlwq.png)

When interacting with *_control2*, *_errorProvider2* will go back to normal, but *_control1*'s *_errorProvider1* will do the same until it is 'clicked'.

[After 'clicking' _control2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drxzh.png)

Please note that underlying Control doesn't affect it; it doesn't have to be CheckBox.

What I tried:

- Using only one ErrorProvider per Form/Control,
- Focusing each Control before setting ErrorProvider,
- Not clearing ErrorProviders

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is no point in using more than one ErrorProvider, one of them can handle errors for all of the controls on a form.  Simplest way to avoid bugs due to trying to herd more than one provider.

Comment: I can't reproduce. Things works as expected. Post a code which reproduces the problem. Also I think following Hans's recommendation should solve your problem.

Comment: I just tried exactly the same code on VS2017 instead of VS2015 (and new .Net version) and it seems to be working @HansPassant I mentioned that I tried both ways and it isn't the issue here. I just posted version with multiple error providers for simplicity.